# Can't remove an old domain from Bing when DNS no longer resolves

Tags: domains, dns, bing, downtime

I'm trying to use Bing's Content Removal page to remove an old domain from search results. The domain belongs to an old staging site and is no longer live, but got picked up by Bing somewhere along the way. When trying to remove the URL Bing returns:

> We could not verify that the URL is no longer live on the web or
>   outdated. Please check the URL for errors or try again later. Your
>   request will not be submitted.

[image: Bing Content Removal]

According their [help page](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/bing-content-removal-tool-cb6c294d)

> If we are unable to determine either (for example, because we **cannot connect to the server on which the page resides**) you will not be able to submit a page removal or outdated cache removal request at this moment in time.

Bing won't be able to connect to the server because it's no longer there. I could go through the trouble of setting the domain up again from scratch and pointing it at a file that just returns a **noindex** header, but that seems a bit silly/overkill to get the page de-listed. Is there any other way to get Bing to de-list this? Why would they make it so difficult to de-list a URL for a domain that doesn't even resolve?

Comment: How long had this site been offline when you attempted this removal?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/block-urls-from-bing-264e560a

There is a block option, I agree this is a sub par solution.